# How to replace list value with Index reference using python

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
U = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

With help of below code, i get below output as

```
 S = []        
 for i in range(0, 5):
    S.append(input("Source:- "))
    print((S[i]))
```

output:

```
S[0] = a 
S[1] = a,b 
S[2] = d,e
...
```

Now i need  to replace the the values of S[] & should get theIndex reference only, as  below one:

```
    S[0] =[ U[0] ] 
    S[1] =[ U[0] , U[1] ]
    S[2] =[ U[3] , U[4] ]
```

How to perform this, any clue pls.

Comment: here's a clue: `list` has a method `index()` which will give you index at which the element is in given list, eg: `["a", "b"].index("b")` gives you `1`, since `b` is at given position in the list. To get a list of items from the input string you have in `S` you can use string's method `split()`: `"a,b".split(",")`gives you `["a", "b"]`

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? Your code seems not to be valid Python, or at least not the desired data/types. ``print((S[i]))`` likely does not output ``S[0] = a`` (unless ``S[0] == "S[0] = a"`` holds true) – did you mean the value of ``S[0]`` is the string ``"a"``? Do you actually want ``S[0] =[ U[0] ] ``, i.e. ``S[0] =["a"]``, or do you want ``S[0] = "[ U[0] ]"`` or something else?

Comment: After splitting up list, how to replace value with index ?

Comment: Yes, I need to replace S[0]=a by  S[0] = [U[0] ]

Comment: What does `S[0] = [U[0]]` mean? Does it mean `S[0] = [0]` and `S[1] = [0, 1]` etc?

Comment: S[0]=a , where a is one of the value in list U=[a,b,c,d,e] but instead i need to reference  it with index instead of value, by S[0]=U[0],

Comment: But, surely `U[0]` is `a` and you already have `S[0] = a`. Anyway, what is it you want to do with `S` when it has the indexes you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming after constructing `S` from user input, it looks like-

```py
['a', 'a,b', 'd,e', ....]
```

And you would like it to look like-

```py
[[0], [0, 1], [3, 4]]
```

(indexes of said characters in `U`)

You could do-

```py
for i, elem in enumerate(S):
    S[i] = [U.index(c) for c in S[i].split(',')]
```

Or if you prefer the pythonic way-

```py
P = [[U.index(c) for c in elem.split(',')] for elem in S]
# This will store the result in `P`
```

### Output

```py
[[0], [0, 1], [3, 4]]
```

Note: This is obviously dependent on user input, but if you want to permit user input like `a, b` as well as `a,b` simply use `S[i].split(',').strip()` instead of just `S[i].split(',')`

Edit: It seems like OP wants the output to be-

```py
`['U[0]', ['U[0]', 'U[1]'], ['U[3]', 'U[4]']]`
```

I'm not sure what is the point of that at all, but here goes anyway-

```py
P = [[f'U[{U.index(c)}]' for c in elem.split(',')] for elem in S]
```

### Output

```py
[['U[0]'], ['U[0]', 'U[1]'], ['U[3]', 'U[4]']]
```

Comment: Above one almost solved, 90% of my expectation.. but any clue to get exact from: U = ['a', 'a,b', 'd,e', ....]  to  [U[0], [U[0],U[1]], [U[3],U[ 4]]]..

Comment: @T.D.Nathan but `U[0]` is just `'a'`, do you mean you want it to be a string? like `['U[0]', ['U[0]', 'U[1]'], ...]`

Comment: Yes I meant like ['U[0]', ['U[0]', 'U[1]'], ...]